# ruby nokogiri HTML table scraping using xpath

Tags: html, ruby, xpath, html-table, nokogiri

I am trying to get "cell4" value that is written in a HTML table like the following using ruby xpath and nokogiri:

```
<html>
<body>

<h1>Heading</h1>

<p>paragraph.</p>

<h4>Two rows and three columns:</h4>
<table border="0">
<tr>
  <td>cell1</td>
  <td>cell2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>cell3</td>
  <td>cell4</td>
</tr>

</table>

</body>
</html>
```

I have the following simple code but it brings []. This question must be simple enough but couldnt find anything that hits the spot on the google

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby -w

require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'

page1 = Nokogiri::HTML('test_simple.html')

a = page1.xpath("//html/body/table/tr[2]/td[2]")
p a
```

the xpath works as intended on REXML therefore it is correct, but does not on nokogiri. Since this is going to be used for larger htmls  REXML cannot be used. The problem does not seem to be only with the tables only other tag contents

or  cannot be scraped as well.

Comment: it should be `Nokogiri::HTML(open('test_simple.html'))`

Comment: it returns something like [#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fb571a59220 name="h1" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fb571a58fa0 "Heading">]>] which the value then be extracted using .text at the end of xpath statement../. thanks!!!

Comment: Assuming you're running IRB from the directory where the 'test_simple.html' file is located something like: `Nokogiri::HTML(open("test_simple.html")).at_xpath("//html/body/table/tr[2]/td[2]").text` should get you what you're looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

thanks to taro`s comment, I was able to solve the issue with some little effort

Here goes the correct code:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby -w
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
page1 = Nokogiri::HTML(open('test_simple.html'))
a = page1.xpath("/html/body/table/tr[2]/td[2]").text
p a
```

Answer (score 7):

IMHO it is a lot asier to work with the CSS API in Nokogiri (XPath is always giving me headaches):

```
page.css('td') # should return an array of 4 table cell nodes
page.css('td')[3] # return the 4th 'td' node, counting starts at 0
```